# GWT ImageResource @source path outside project folder

Tags: gwt, clientbundle

in my project, i am using a `ClientBundle` for my images used in the project. The images I would be using were already used by other non-`gwt` project, a `Flex` web application so these images are placed in a single directory found outside my `gwt` project.

hierarchy:

```
server
 - image
     - myimage.gif
 - gwtprojects
     - myproject
        - com.gwt.sample
           - CImageResource.java
```

In my CImageResource class:

```
@Source("../../../../../image/myimage.gif")
ImageResource myImage();
```

And gwt says "Resource file is missing".

How can i used the image in my `ClientBundle` class?
As much as possible, I don't wanna copy the image i'm gonna use in my project folder if there's a way to access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT loads everything from the classpath, so just put the `image` folder in the classpath and you can reference your `myimage.gif` with `@Source("myimage.gif")`, `@Source("/myimage.gif")` or `@Source("../../../myimage.gif")`.